# function for making a string out of an object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I need to make a function that generates a string from an object's key/value pairs.
The string should be : `"key = value, key = value"`. with spacing around the `=` and each key/value pair separated by a comma and space except for the last one.

So `{a: "1'", b: "2"}` would be `"a = 1, b = 2"`.

I'm trying to learn so don't give me the code straight up, I mostly need to know where I'm wrong and guided to find the right answer.
i currently have :

```
   const obj = {};
const string = [];
string = (string.join( ', ' ));
function stringFromObject(obj){
    for (const [keys, values] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    string.push(`${keys} = ${values}`);
    console.log (string.join( ', ' ));
    
  }
  return string.toString();
}
```

Comment: Why do you reassign `{}` to `obj` inside the function ? It just wipes out the content of what you put as a parameter. Besides, `keys()` and `values()` don't return a string, but a list of objects. You need to loop through those and concatenate each value to your string.

Comment: Your updated code with the `for … of` loop looks better, it has all the relevant parts but in the wrong position. Move the `const string = []` inside the function so that each invocation gets a new array. Remove `const obj = {};` and `string = (string.join( ', ' ));`. Use the `string.join( ', ' )` instead of `string.toString()` for your return value.

Answer (score 0):

Because you asked for a guidance and not the answer straight up:

One way to do this is using the native `stringify` function.
In JavaScript an object can be stringified as if it was a JSON string, with `JSON.stringify()` static method. For example the `{a: 1, b: 2}` object stringifies as *{"a":1,"b":2}*.

Now that you got that string at hand, you can use any number of string modifier functions on it to format it to your desired way. For example you can replace `:` with  `=`  (including whitespaces) like:

```js
function stringFromObject(obj) {
    let string = JSON.stringify(obj);
    // {"a":1,"b":2}
    string = string.replaceAll(":", " = ");
    // {"a" = 1, "b" = 2}
    //...
}
```

I guess you can now figure the whole thing out, right?
You can carry on replacing until you get your desired format.

```js
    string = string.replaceAll(":", " = ").replaceAll("\"", "");
    // {a = 1,b = 2}
    //...
```

If you are familiar with **Regex**, you can probably do the whole set of changes in one or two steps.

Another way could be looping through the key-value pairs. It works well for flat objects (where there are no nested objects) or you will need to recursively go through them. That would be a bit painful and unnecessarily slower way in case of large, nested objects, considering the speed and convenience the native functionality offers.

The main issue with your solution is that you replace the incoming object with an empty object, so nothing will be printed because there is nothing to be printed. The other issue is that `Object.keys` and `Object.values` each return an array (not a string) even if there is one key to show it will be an array of one member, so you should get the arrays member. Lastly, even if you fix those issues the current function only works for one pair (unless you call this function from within another loop).

Comment: No, don't use `JSON.stringify` and weird string replacement rules to create a custom serialisation. OP really should use (and learn) the looping. I also doubt that there is any significant performance difference.

Comment: I gave my answer a good  thought and candidly chose the order of methods. I also mentioned that as a way, but how a very early stage beginner to detect and recursively loop through a nested object or etc.? I considered the fact s/he reassigned the obj and that he added an array to a string before coming to the decision in ordering. My answer isn't wrong and didn't fairly deserve a negative only because you prefer some other way better!

Comment: I doubt they would need to handle nested objects. But yes, the goal of the exercise is to learn looping, which they would need to understand before they could even comprehend what `JSON.stringify` or `replaceAll` do. A regex approach is definitely not suitable for a beginner - but a lot of replacements would need to be done on a json text to arrive at the desired output. And "carrying on with more string replacements until it looks right" is really bad advice imo, it is not a viable algorithmic approach and should not be taught/shown to beginners.

Comment: Thank you, this would be my first time using JSON.stringify, i tried it before i changed the code that i asked about but i must've formatted it wrong.  i am a beginner but i use loops often and the project i'm doing has 14 functions inside it. i have 4 left but all of the others i used a loop for.

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate strings without intermediate arrays, that would be much faster. Also you could add recursion to dump nested objects:

```js
 const obj = {a: "1", b: "2", c: {d: "3", e: "4" }};
 
 const dumpObj = (obj, out = '') => {
    for(const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)){
        out += (out ? ', ' : '')  + (typeof v === 'object' ? `${k} = {${dumpObj(v)}}` : `${k} = ${v}`);
    }
    return out;  
 };
 
 console.log(dumpObj(obj));
```

Answer (score -4):

```js
function stringFromObject(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([k, v]) => `${k} = ${v}`)
    .join(', ')
}

console.log(stringFromObject({ a: 1, b: 2 }))
```

Comment: I doubt this is explaining anything, the solution is obviously working but a beginner wouldn't comprehend this without any explanation

Comment: This does exactly what the OP is asking for. The code is self explanatory. If some parts are not understood, they are available in the Javascript MDN documentation.
`Object.entries`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries
`Array.map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: This is a fine solution, but lacks any explanation and goes straight against the requirement "*don't give me the code straight up*". It also doesn't answer the question about the problem with the OP's current code.

Comment: @JavierRey The code does what the OP described, but this is not what they asked for.

Comment: Thank you for the links, Javier. and i wouldnt mind learning the loop for it Bergi. any help is appreciated i know there are many different ways.